# Finite solvable group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group such that $(|G|, 15)=1$. Why $G$ is solvable group?

Comment: Is there any reason to think that this question will have an answer simpler than the proof of the odd order theorem, which is the same claim with $2$ in place of $15$?

Comment: @David Speyer: I have studied in a paper " it is not hard to prove by the classification that if $(|G|,15)=1$, then $G$ is solvable". So I thought that it has an answer simpler.

Comment: If you allow the classification, the odd order theorem is proved the same way: Look at the table of finite noncyclic simple groups; notice they all have even order.

Comment: I think the odd order theorem is an explicit step in the Classification, while the "$(G,15)$ is not.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-group_(finite_group_theory)

Comment: What Yves said: Thompson's classification of minimal non-solvable groups depends on the odd order theorem, and to the best of my knowledge no proof of the "$(|G|,15)=1$ theorem" is known which doesn't depend on Thompson's result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We note that the Suzuki groups are only non-Abelian simple groups of order
prime to $3$ and $5$ is a prime divisor of the Suzuki groups. Let $G$ be
unsolvable group, then $G$ has the following normal series:
$1\unlhd K\lhd M\unlhd G$ such that $M/K$ is a non-Abelian simple group (and or $M/K\cong S\times $ $
S\cdot \cdot \cdot \times S$ where $S$ is non-Abelian simple group). As $
3\nmid |G|$, then $M/K$ is a Suzuki group ( and or $M/K\cong S\times $ $
S\cdot \cdot \cdot \times S$ where $S$ is a Suzuki group). On the other hand
$5\nmid |G|$, then $M/K$ is not isomorphic to a Suzuki group (and or $
M/K\ncong S\times $ $S\cdot \cdot \cdot \times S$ where $S$ is a Suzuki
group), a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

Because as you go through the list of finite simple noncyclic groups, you can observe that their orders are divisible by either 3 or 5. In fact, only a few of them, for instance, $\,^2B_2(8)$, will have orders not divisible by 3...

Off course, this argument depends on the classification... Maybe, there is a trick to show it directly...

Comment: Certainly, one should be able to get away with Thompson's classification of minimal non-solvable groups, which predates the classification.